# How to define variable in Webpack for eslint in case of DefinePlugin using

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, webpack

I am working with Webpack 2 and Bootstrap 4.

I provided some global variables and it's working for me, but when I tried to use eslint it shows to me:  *no-undef error*

it's because I didn't import that variable.

But how I can do that if it's global? 
code below is working fine except it fails on the eslint.
provide.plugin

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    jQuery : "jquery",
    $ : "jquery",
    jquery : "jquery",
    Tether: "tether",
    "window.Tether": "tether",
    Alert: "exports-loader?Alert!bootstrap/js/dist/alert",
    Button: "exports-loader?Button!bootstrap/js/dist/button",
    Carousel: "exports-loader?Carousel!bootstrap/js/dist/carousel",
    Collapse: "exports-loader?Collapse!bootstrap/js/dist/collapse",
    Dropdown: "exports-loader?Dropdown!bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown",
    Popover: "exports-loader?Popover!bootstrap/js/dist/popover",
    Scrollspy: "exports-loader?Scrollspy!bootstrap/js/dist/scrollspy",
    Tab: "exports-loader?Tab!bootstrap/js/dist/tab",
    Tooltip: "exports-loader?Tooltip!bootstrap/js/dist/tooltip",
    Util: "exports-loader?Util!bootstrap/js/dist/util",
    Modal: "exports-loader?Modal!bootstrap/js/dist/modal"
})
```

and here is my code

```
console.log(Modal);

setTimeout(() => {
    const a = new Modal($("#myModal")[0]);
    console.log(a);
    a.show();
}, 2000);
```

I tried to create an alias for Modal but it's isn't working

webpack.conf

```
alias: {
    Modal: "exports-loader?Modal!bootstrap/js/dist/modal",
}
```

component.js

```
  import Modal from "Modal";
    import $ from "jquery";
    console.log(Modal);

setTimeout(() => {
    const a = new Modal($("#myModal")[0]);
    console.log(a);
    a.show();
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

eslint does not know anything about any variables that have been made available globally through webpack. You should specify them either in each file by defining any global vars in the first line `/* global var1, var2 */`, or better use the `.eslintrc` file to define them only once. See also the explanation in their [docs](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals).

Comment: I resolved that issue by "bootstrap splitting". I import one of bootstrap modules and elsint is working fine in that case. But I should initialize Bootstrap Component manually and it's isn't good. You variant a little bit better

Answer (score 3):

Came to this question because vscode wasn't detecting webpack defined globals with definePlugin, solution with `.eslintrc.js` as per the eslint docs

> ### Using configuration files
>
> To configure global variables inside of a
> configuration file, set the globals configuration property to an
> object containing keys named for each of the global variables you want
> to use. For each global variable key, set the corresponding value
> equal to "writable" to allow the variable to be overwritten or
> "readonly" to disallow overwriting. For example:

```
{
    "globals": {
        "var1": "writable",
        "var2": "readonly"
    }
}
```